# $L^1$ bounded martingale

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales, quadratic-variation

If $(M_t)_{0\leq t<\infty}$ is continuous martingale and it is $L^1$ bounded, does it imply that quadratic variation $\langle M\rangle_\infty$ is finite a.s. ?

Comment: I deleted my answer. A [remark in Revuz-Yor](http://books.google.fr/books?id=1ml95FLM5koC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA55#v=onepage) says that a $L^1$ bounded martingale may not have integrable supremum. If you have that $M_t \log^+ M_t$ is bounded in $L^1$ then the expectation of the supremum is bounded and you can apply my argument.
Maybe something more subtle is needed to prove the general case

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it does.  I will flesh out what mike probably had in mind.

For $b > 0$, let $T_b = \inf\{t : |M_t| \ge b\}$.  Since $M_t$ is continuous, for any $t$ we have $|M_{T_b \wedge t}| \le b$.   Now $M_t^2 - \langle M \rangle_t$ is a martingale, so by optional stopping we have, for any $t$,
$$E[\langle M \rangle_{T_b \wedge t}] = E[M_{T_b \wedge t}^2] \le b^2.$$

Letting $t \to \infty$ and using Fatou's lemma, we have $E[\langle M \rangle_{T_b}] \le b^2 < \infty$; in particular, $\langle M \rangle_\infty < \infty$ a.s. on $\{T_b = \infty\}$.  (Note of course that $\langle M \rangle_t$ is an increasing process, so $\langle M \rangle_\infty$ makes sense.)  So $\langle M \rangle_\infty < \infty$ almost surely on the event $A := \bigcup_{b \in \mathbb{N}} \{T_b = \infty\}$.  But $A$ is precisely the event that $M_t$ is bounded (that there exists some $b$ which is never reached; here we have used continuity of $M_t$ again).

But $M_t$ is $L^1$ bounded, so by the martingale convergence theorem, $M_t$ converges almost surely.  Thus $M_t$ is almost surely bounded, and we have $P(A) = 1$, which completes the proof.

Comment: Thank you very much Nate! The proof is very elegant and clear

Comment: Nate Eldredge: Indeed very nice proof. Thank's I've learned something today. Best regards

Comment: Hi, may I ask why is $M_t^2 - \langle{M}\rangle_t$ a martingale? It doesn't seem to be true even if we consider discrete-time martingales. Let $X$ be a random variable such that $\mathbb{E}[|X|] < \infty$ but $\mathbb{E}[X^2] = \infty$. Then let $M_t = X$ for all $t$. Then clearly $M_t$ is a martingale which is $L^1$-bounded, but $M_t^2 - \langle{M}\rangle_t$ is not $L^1$ bounded, so it is not a martingale (of course in this case it's trivial that the quadratic variation is bounded, but I'm saying that your argument appears to break down).

Comment: @ClementYung: I'm assuming here that $M_t$ is an $L^2$ martingale.  This is normally assumed whenever you talk about quadratic variation, because you need $L^2$ for it to even make sense.  So to be clear, we are assuming that each $E[M_t^2]$ is finite (but they could be unbounded in $t$), and that $\sup_t E[|M_t|] < \infty$ ($L^1$ bounded).  And for $L^2$ martingales it is true that $M_t^2 - \langle M \rangle_t$ is a martingale; this is often taken as the definition of $\langle M \rangle_t$.

Answer (score 1):

yes, since it converges, being L1 bounded, its sample paths will be the same as those of the process stopped when you hit $\pm K$ for a large K with high probability, and  so are the same, with high probability, as those of a $\mathbb L^2$ bounded martingale.

Comment: @ Mike : I just don"t get it. Regards

Comment: @ Mike : I now get it form Nate Eldredge's post. Best regards